# Can DirectSound play a raw binary sound file?

Tags: file, directsound

I took a binary file encoded in U-law and decoded it to PCM. Now I need to play it. However, it has no WAV header.

Can DirectSound play a raw binary sound file that has no WAV header?

Comment: -1. I've cleaned up this question a bit, but it still seems somewhat pointless. Apart from the question *if* this is possible, didn't you, perhaps, also want to know *how* it is done?

Answer (score 0):

It has been years since I did any DX programming, but it certainly should be possible to place the sound data in an appropriately formatted sound buffer. The header of a WAV just sets the number of channels, bitrate etc on the sound buffer, which you can set yourself manually.

You can always have the fallback of writing your raw data to a wav format file first (there are C# sample apps about).